# involved in or involved

Tags: word-choice

What is the correct form to say that you have been involved in a project so that would be  the sentence's subject ?
Example : 
First project I was involved in is X.
or
First project I was involved is X .
I heard my project manager using the second form , but it doesn't sound right to me .

Comment: you're right, the second one isn't correct. "Am Involved" (and all of its tenses, including is involved, was involved, were involved, etc.) doesn't make sense without a preposition (e.g. with). You could say "I involved the project", but that only works because it lacks "am"

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you. The second construct does not read well. To take two related examples: "I was involved in a project" is correct usage whereas "I was involved a project" is almost meaningless. Similarly, your first version makes perfect sense but the second is almost meaningless. Your manager may be mixing up two uses in his ill-managed language: "The project involves me" and "I am involved in the project".